# Spring MVC and Backbone jQuery Template conflict

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone-views, jquery-templates

Am developing an application with Spring MVC and Backbone with jQuery template.

I found a weird conflict, as both Spring MVC and jQuery template are using the same syntax to denote a variable

```
${ variable }
```

So, When i declare a template like this

```
<script id="appointment-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                        <li><a href="#" data-id="${eventId}">${title}</a></li>
```

Spring MVC treats this ${eventId} as Spring variable and removes it, making it unavailable for the template engine to apply the changes!

How to resolve this conflict!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to solve the problem.

Solution:

Use any other conflict free pattern, like

```
<script id="appointment-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                        <li><a href="#" data-id="@{eventId}">@{title}</a></li>
```

In the , backed js, replace the pattern with jQuery pattern

```
var temp = $('#appointment-template').text().replace(/@/g,'$');
var template = $('#appointment-template').text(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

By Spring MVC, I guess you mean jspx views. For jspx you could try the following, so that `${variable}` is not interpreted on the server side.

```
<script id="appointment-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  // <![CDATA[
    <li><a href="#" data-id="${eventId}">${title}</a></li>
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but am not using jspx

Comment: so what are you using? it is not clear from the problem statement. What ever is your view technology, the solution will be similar lines. Wrap the script in approriate comment block so that it is not interpreted on the serverside.